# DS1307 RTC module using without arduino?

Tags: arduino, timer, delay, rtc

Is it possible to use RTC module DS1307 to schedule swtiching lights on and off? I am not supposed to use arduino but all tutorials on internet are with arduino.

---

The main problem for me is power consumption. I need to reduce it as less as possible. Well, my circuit needs about 30mA for normally working. That is (30*24)mAh on daily base, but I need to power it for 2 years with 10000mAh battery. My goal is to every 8 hours turn on circuit for 1minute and turn it off.

I was searching for different 12V timers but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Don't ask "Is it possible..." because the fact that things are possible doesn't mean **you** can do them or that it is a **good idea** or that it is a **practical solution**. To read out the data of a DS1307 you need to follow a certain sequence (it uses I2C). It **is** possible to make a logic circuit that can do this but it will be **huge and complex**. It is **much, much easier** to use a microcontroller for that. There are many, many microcontrollers and microprocessors that can do that but that are not called "Arduino". So get a PIC controller and use that.

Comment: Why do you have the constraint of not using Arduio? It's not clear for me if it's a XY problem here: Do you want to solve a physical problem such as scheduling the switching of lights? That case the usage of a DS1307 may not be the best way to achieve your goal at all... Or is it that, for some reason that you should explain to us, you are forced to use a DS1307 in your project. You may have very good reason: You already have some around. It's a school project and you have that constraint,... If you want us to help you, you should provide more contextual information.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, you seem to lack basic understanding on serial buses. Did you read the datasheet of this clock unit? If so, which part did you understand and which not?

Comment: *My goal is to every 8 hours turn on circuit for 1minute and turn it off.* Then why use a DS1307? That's overkill. The DS1307 does **a lot more** like keeping time of day and keeping track of the date. 1 minute every 8 hours is something you can do with a HEF4060 and some additional logic.

Comment: Your question is a **classic example** of an XY problem, describing the (what you think is) a possible solution (using a DS1307) while for the task (1minute every 8 hours) that really isn't a good solution. Instead focus on **describing the task** and then ask for suggestions. Suggesting your own ideas (even when they're bad ideas) is appreciated. So: should I use a DS1307 or ... ? And not: I am going to use the DS1307, how to do that without a micro.

Comment: You say "I am not supposed to use arduino": could you tell us what's permitted?  A non-Arduino ATMega?  Arduino hardware but not development environment?  A different microcontroller such as ATtiny or STM?  There are lots of ways to turn things on and off but we don't know your constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is possible, see [this project](https://www.electronicwings.com/pic/real-time-clock-rtc-ds1307-interfacing-with-pic18f4550) where they use a DS1307, a display and a PIC microcontroller to make a real time clock.

It should be fairly easy to change the code and make an output drive a relay to switch on/off your lights at certain times.

The Arduino isn't the only microcontroller platform. I fail to see the reason why you cannot use an Arduino if a PIC microcontroller would be allowed. Both platforms are very similar.

If you are not allowed to use **any** microcontroller or microprocessor then things will be difficult if you insist on using the DS1307. Is using the DS1307 a hard requirement or can a different timer function be used as well?

**Edit**, seeing your comments, indeed you really do not need to use a DS1307. Actually you're making your life difficult if you just want: "*My goal is to every 8 hours turn on circuit for 1minute and turn it off*".

In the old days a HEF4060, clocking that from mains 50 Hz and some additional logic was all that's needed to make a ligh timer. Unfortunately designing that seems like a lost art these days.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Either by creating a \$I^2C\$-Interface from scratch or by using a different microcontroller than a preconfigured arduino.

But judging from your question you probably won't be able to do either without a really prolonged learning phase. Think of 2 years intense study to build a hard coded bus interface from scratch or 1 year to get into μC programming.

If you go through a tutorial you may be able to master it with an arduino and a RTC shield in 1 month or even shorter.